# Is there any way to extract the names of columns from an excel sheet without actually loading the sheet into the RAM?

Tags: r

I'm working on a R Project and I wanna check if there is any way to extract the column names without loading the entire excel sheet to the RAM.

Comment: Maybe you could use the nrows parameter from data.tables fread and set it to 1. So only the first row should be loaded.

Comment: `fread` is for CSV-ish files, not Excel workbooks @TinglTanglBob

Comment: Welcome to SO. _"Excel sheet"_ → `.xls`? `.xlsx`? or, is it a `.csv` file (as assumed by the first comment)? _"Column names"_  → is your Excel sheet uniform so the first row is made up of well-formed columns or is it a structured sheet with formatting that might not make it straightforward to read in column names? Why the _load into RAM"_ avoidance? Excel workbooks rarely are large enough to warrant concern when reading into R. Your answers should be put into the question text, not responded to as a comment. More detail in your question will result in better answers.

Comment: I'm interning in a software company and this was the task that was assigned to me @hrbrmstr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(xlsx)

out<- read.xlsx(file.xlsx, sheetIndex = 1,startRow = 1, endRow = 2, header= T)
```

this will only load 1st row of your excel sheet, which will not take up much of your RAM.

Comment: I tried this but I keep on getting the unused argument error for endRow

Comment: use the same syntax, just change the file name in file.xlsx ,it should work, it is working in my pc